# Angular ng build --prod, output index.html produces nothing

Tags: angular, build

I've seen tutorials where after running the ng build --prod they can go into the dist folder and just run the index.html from there. But when I do this nothing happens. I can add a p tag above  and it shows up, so why wouldn't the app-root?

Console output:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

Comment: Is something serving the other static files? Do you see them getting loaded in the network tab? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///runtime-es2015.1eba213af0b233498d9d.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).

Answer (score 0):

You need to open `index.html` using `HTTP` hyper text transfer protocol not file, so i recommend you to use http-server 
`npm install http-server -g` then run `http-server dist`